# Pass Javascript variable to Google Script function (Google Sheets)

Tags: javascript, html, image, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a JavaScript function which is taking the src value

```
<div>
  <img src="theUrl" id="imgID" onclick="myImageUrl()" />
</div>

<script>

  function myImageUrl() {
    var q = document.getElementById(imgID).src;
      google.script.run
       .imageCell();
  }

</script>
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to pass this into a Google apps function so I can implement the image URL into a cell such as

```
function imageCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getActiveRange();

  range.setValue(q);
}
```

UPDATE:

Thank Amit but unless I'm missing something this didn't allow for the value to be used a saved var. I ran it both ways

HTML

```
 <div id="theImageUrl">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" id="theImageUrl" onclick="getImage()" />      
    </div>
    <script>
        function getImage() {
            q = document.getElementById( 'theImageUrl ).src;
            google.script.run.imageCell(q);
            }
        </script>
```

Verified by my fiddle [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aU2H2/24/)

Server Side

```
function imageCell(q) {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var range = ss.getActiveRange();

range.setValue(q);
}
```

*Both .setValue(q) & .setValue();

Comment: Use the debugger in Apps Script to debug your code.  [Troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)  Provide specific information about the error message, and what line the error occurred on.  View the Execution Transcript in the Script Editor to determine if the code executed successfully or not.  Errors in the browser with HTML will be shown in the browsers console.

Comment: Use a `Logger.log('image is: ' + q)` statement in the `imageCell()` function.  Then VIEW the LOGS after the code has run.  What prints to the Logs?

Answer (score 0):

On the HTML side:

`google.script.run.imageCell(q);`

And on the server side:

`function imageCell(q) { ...`

Comment: Thanks Amit but this didn't seem to work. I have updated my question with your code to showcase what was used.

Comment: One more change is required. Since you are using the HTMLService, you can only access the sheet through the SpeadsheetApp.openById() method.

Comment: If the HTML is in a Dialog Box, `getActiveSpreadsheet()` should work.